# Is there a way to mask a matrix in matlab based on elements in an array?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a matrix `a = [1,2,3;4,1,2;3,4,2]`.

I need to create a logical matrix which is `1` wherever there is an element of `b` in `a`. The equivalent of `a==4 | a==1` if my array `b` is a small one like `[1,4]`.

I know one way to do this is:

```
b = [1,4];
c = logical(zeros(size(a)));
for i=b
    c = c | a==i;
end
```

This solution may not scale well if `a` and `b` are large. Is there a cleaner way to do it for larger arrays?

I was hoping `a == b` would give me what i wanted, but it doesn't.

Comment: `+` gives a `double` matrix whereas the logical `|` gives a logical matrix. The two operations are otherwise identical.
I am actually looking for a solution for larger arrays than just `[1,4]`

Comment: Well, isn't `logical()` just a roundabout way of achieving what the logical OR operator would do anyway?
I have made edits to make the question a little more explicit about scalability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ismember` to output a logical array which is true whenever an element of the first input is a member of the second input. The output is the same size as the first input.

```
c = ismember( a, b );
```

In your example:

```
a = [1,2,3;
     4,1,2;
     3,4,2];
b = [1,4];
c = ismember( a, b );
% >> c = 
%    [1,0,0;
%     1,1,0;
%     0,1,0]
```